# tkinter app using lots of processing power

Tags: python, tkinter, optimization

I've been making an Enigma Machine simulator (python with `tkinter`), but for some reason, it absolutely eats up my CPU even though it's not a big program. I've been trying to figure out how to optimize it. I've only had 1 python class in 6th grade with `pygame`, so this is all stuff I'm not familiar with. Help with optimization would be greatly appreciated!
This code will work just by pasting into an IDLE window.

```
"""
Enigma.py
Made by R.D. 2022
https://github.com/briocherockets
https://www.reddit.com/user/BriocheRockets
"""

# ROTOR VARIABLE GLOSSARY
# "rotorX1"  1,1,1 wiring, pre-slicing into lists and functions
# "rotorX"  R1, R2, and R3 are procedural shuffled alphabets from sending the alphabet through the wiring functions
# "rotorXf"  Wiring, stored as a function that 1-26 is sent through to be reassigned
# "rotorXtick" 1-26 tick variable

# LIBRARIES
import tkinter as tk
import sys

# WINDOW SETUP
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Enigma")
window.geometry("700x550")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# INPUT/OUTPUT BOXES
outputbox = tk.Text(window, height=6, width=75, font=("Calibri", 12))
inputbox = tk.Text(window, height=6, width=75, font=("Calibri", 12))
outputbox.place(x=50, y=50)
inputbox.place(x=50, y=380)
lettercount = 0

# ROTOR ROTATION DISPLAYS
rotor1box = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=2, font=("Calibri", 20))
rotor2box = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=2, font=("Calibri", 20))
rotor3box = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=2, font=("Calibri", 20))
rotor1box.place(x=80, y=255)
rotor2box.place(x=130, y=255)
rotor3box.place(x=180, y=255)

# TEMPORARY ROTOR VARIABLES (FOR STORAGE BEFORE CONVERSION INTO LIST
rotor11 = "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ"
rotor21 = "AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE"
rotor31 = "BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO"
ref1 = "YRUHQSLDPXNGOKMIEBFZCWVJAT"
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
# ROTOR LISTS
rotor1 = []
rotor2 = []
rotor3 = []
rotor1f = []
rotor2f = []
rotor3f = []
ref = []
numbers = list(range(1, 27))
# EXTRA VALUES
rotor1turnover = 17
rotor2turnover = 5
rotor3turnover = 22
rotor1tick = 1
rotor2tick = 1
rotor3tick = 1
rotors = [rotor1, rotor2, rotor3, ref, rotor1f, rotor2f, rotor3f]
rotorticks = [rotor1tick, rotor2tick, rotor3tick]
# SAVEWIRING SETUP
# TEXTBOXES
rot1 = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=26, font=("Consolas", 13))
rot2 = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=26, font=("Consolas", 13))
rot3 = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=26, font=("Consolas", 13))
refl = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=26, font=("Consolas", 13))
rot1.place(x=380, y=210)
rot2.place(x=380, y=240)
rot3.place(x=380, y=270)
refl.place(x=380, y=300)
# LABELS
alph = tk.Label(window, text="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", font=("Consolas", 13)).place(
    x=379, y=180
)
r1t = tk.Label(window, text="Rotor 1:", font=("Consolas", 15)).place(x=260, y=210)
r2t = tk.Label(window, text="Rotor 2:", font=("Consolas", 15)).place(x=260, y=240)
r3t = tk.Label(window, text="Rotor 3:", font=("Consolas", 15)).place(x=260, y=270)
reft = tk.Label(window, text="Reflector:", font=("Consolas", 15)).place(x=260, y=300)


def save():
    global rotor1
    global rotor2
    global rotor3
    global ref
    global rotors
    rotor11 = rot1.get("1.0", "end")
    rotor21 = rot2.get("1.0", "end")
    rotor31 = rot3.get("1.0", "end")
    ref1 = refl.get("1.0", "end")
    rotor1 = []
    rotor2 = []
    rotor3 = []
    ref = []
    rotor1f = []
    rotor2f = []
    rotor3f = []
    for i in range(0, 26):
        rotor3.append(alpha.find(rotor31[i]) + 1)
        rotor2.append(alpha.find(rotor21[i]) + 1)
        rotor1.append(alpha.find(rotor11[i]) + 1)
        ref.append(alpha.find(ref1[i]) + 1)
        rotor3f.append(alpha.find(rotor31[i]) - i)
        rotor2f.append(alpha.find(rotor21[i]) - i)
        rotor1f.append(alpha.find(rotor11[i]) - i)
    #        print
    #    for i in range(0, 26):
    #        rotor1.append(rotor11[i])
    #        rotor2.append(rotor21[i])
    #        rotor3.append(rotor31[i])
    #        ref.append(ref1[i])
    rotors = [rotor1, rotor2, rotor3, ref, rotor1f, rotor2f, rotor3f]


savewiring = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="Save Wiring",
    font=("Calibri", 13),
    command=save,
    activebackground="Grey",
    activeforeground="Grey",
)
savewiring.place(x=440, y=328)


# FINAL SETUPS
# TAKE STRINGS AND CONVERT TO LISTS
for i in range(0, 26):
    rotor3.append(alpha.find(rotor31[i]) + 1)
    rotor2.append(alpha.find(rotor21[i]) + 1)
    rotor1.append(alpha.find(rotor11[i]) + 1)
    ref.append(alpha.find(ref1[i]) + 1)
    rotor3f.append(alpha.find(rotor31[i]) - i)
    rotor2f.append(alpha.find(rotor21[i]) - i)
    rotor1f.append(alpha.find(rotor11[i]) - i)
# INSERT VALUES TO BOXES
rot1.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor1)))
rot2.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor2)))
rot3.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor3)))
refl.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, ref)))
# EEEEEEEEE
strip = ""
# ^dont remove or else it breaks everything lol
enigma = True  # enigma balls lol


def change(rotor, reversebool):
    global active
    if rotor == 4:
        active = ref[active - 1]
    elif reversebool is True:
        active = active + (rotors[rotor + 3])[active - 1]
        if active > 26:
            active -= 26
        if active < 1:
            active += 26
    elif reversebool is False:
        active = active - (rotors[rotor + 3])[(rotors[rotor - 1]).index(active)]
        if active > 26:
            active -= 26
        if active < 1:
            active += 26


def encrypt():
    change(3, True)
    change(2, True)
    change(1, True)
    change(4, True)
    change(1, False)
    change(2, False)
    change(3, False)


def rotincrement(rotor, reversebool):
    global rotor1tick
    global rotor2tick
    global rotor3tick
    global rotors
    if reversebool is False:
        temprot = (rotors[rotor + 3])[0]
        del (rotors[rotor + 3])[0]
        (rotors[rotor + 3]).insert(25, temprot)
        if rotorticks[rotor - 1] < 26:
            rotorticks[rotor - 1] += 1
        else:
            rotorticks[rotor - 1] = 1

    else:
        temprot = (rotors[rotor + 3])[25]
        del (rotors[rotor + 3])[25]
        (rotors[rotor + 3]).insert(0, temprot)
        if rotorticks[rotor - 1] > 1:
            rotorticks[rotor - 1] -= 1
        else:
            rotorticks[rotor - 1] = 26
    for i in range(0, 26):
        (rotors[rotor - 1])[i] = (rotors[rotor + 3])[i] + i + 1
        if (rotors[rotor - 1])[i] > 26:
            (rotors[rotor - 1])[i] -= 26
        elif (rotors[rotor - 1])[i] < 1:
            (rotors[rotor - 1])[i] += 26


def rotate(count, reversebool):
    global rotor1
    global rotor2
    global rotor3
    global rotor1tick
    global rotor2tick
    global rotor3tick
    # ROLL FORWARD
    if reversebool is False:
        rotincrement(3, False)
        if rotorticks[2] == rotor3turnover:
            rotincrement(2, False)
            if rotorticks[1] == rotor2turnover:
                rotincrement(1, False)
    # ROLL BACKWARD
    elif reversebool is True:
        for i in range(1, count + 1):
            rotincrement(3, True)
            if rotorticks[2] == rotor3turnover - 1:
                rotincrement(2, True)
                if rotorticks[1] == rotor2turnover - 1:
                    rotincrement(1, True)


# DEFINE BUTTONS FOR ROTOR SETTING
r1plus = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="➕",
    font=("Calibri", 12),
    command=lambda: rotincrement(1, False),
    activebackground="Grey",
    activeforeground="Grey",
).place(x=80, y=200)
r2plus = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="➕",
    font=("Calibri", 12),
    command=lambda: rotincrement(2, False),
    activebackground="Grey",
    activeforeground="Grey",
).place(x=130, y=200)
r3plus = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="➕",
    font=("Calibri", 12),
    command=lambda: rotincrement(3, False),
    activebackground="Grey",
    activeforeground="Grey",
).place(x=180, y=200)
r1min = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="➖",
    font=("Calibri", 12),
    command=lambda: rotincrement(1, True),
    activebackground="Grey",
    activeforeground="Grey",
).place(x=80, y=310)
r2min = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="➖",
    font=("Calibri", 12),
    command=lambda: rotincrement(2, True),
    activebackground="Grey",
    activeforeground="Grey",
).place(x=130, y=310)
r3min = tk.Button(
    window,
    text="➖",
    font=("Calibri", 12),
    command=lambda: rotincrement(3, True),
    activebackground="Grey",
    activeforeground="Grey",
).place(x=180, y=310)


"""
Main loop
"""
while enigma:
    # UPDATE UI ROTORTICKS/USER INPUT
    try:
        rotor3box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        rotor3box.insert("1.0", rotorticks[2])
        rotor2box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        rotor2box.insert("1.0", rotorticks[1])
        rotor1box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        rotor1box.insert("1.0", rotorticks[0])
        uinput = inputbox.get("1.0", tk.END)
    except Exception:
        sys.exit()
    # LETTER COUNT UPDATE DETECTION
    if lettercount != len(uinput):
        if lettercount < len(uinput) and len(uinput) > 1:
            if len(uinput) - lettercount > 1:
                for i in range(1, len(uinput) - lettercount + 1):
                    active = alpha.find(uinput[i - 1].upper()) + 1
                    rotate(1, False)
                    encrypt()
                    outputbox.insert(tk.END, alpha[active - 1])
            else:
                active = alpha.find(uinput[len(uinput) - 2].upper()) + 1
                rotate(1, False)
                encrypt()
                outputbox.insert(tk.END, alpha[active - 1])
        elif lettercount > len(uinput):
            if lettercount - len(uinput) < 2:
                rotate(1, True)
                uoutput = outputbox.get("1.0", tk.END)
                strip = uoutput[:-2]
                outputbox.delete("1.0", tk.END)
                outputbox.insert("1.0", strip)
            else:
                rotate(lettercount - len(uinput), True)
                uoutput = outputbox.get("1.0", tk.END)
                strip = uoutput[: ((lettercount - len(uinput)) * -1) - 1]
                outputbox.delete("1.0", tk.END)
                outputbox.insert("1.0", strip)
        # UPDATE ROTOR WIRING BOXES
        rot1.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        rot1.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor11)))
        rot2.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        rot2.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor21)))
        rot3.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        rot3.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor31)))
        refl.delete("1.0", tk.END)
        refl.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, ref1)))
    # REDEFINE LETTERCOUNT
    lettercount = len(uinput)
    window.update()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and include it in the question. StackOverflow discourages linking to code on another site.

Comment: Please don't post links to off-site sources. Put your code in your questions.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer, and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: Hi @furas, it's not a syntax error, rather it's a question about how to optimize my program to use less resources. For the codeblocks, the comments i had were messing it up, and i couldn't figure out how to fix that. Thank you for the comments, though, I'll keep them in mind for any future posts i make!

Comment: Apologies, @martineau, the comments i had in my script were messing the codeblocks up and i couldn't figure out how to get around that. I'll keep this in mind for any future posts. Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: I didn't ask for error message but I wrote to always put code as text, not link to external server.

Comment: @brioche I've reformatted your code with [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/), fixed all the errors and warnings shown by [pylama](https://pypi.org/project/pylama/), converted the text blocks to comments  and added the code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the way you have written your own `mainloop` keeps the CPU pegged because there is no pause in your `while`-loop.

A quick fix would be to add e.g. `time.sleep(0.05)` to your loop.

But a better solution would be to rewrite it in a canonical way.
The original enigma machine does its "calculation" when you press a key. So it would make sense to link the calculation to a key event.

Use the standard `mainloop`, and `bind` a function to update the encryption to the `<Key>` event.

```
def handle_key(event):
    try:
        rotor3box.delete("1.0", END)
        rotor3box.insert("1.0", rotorticks[2])
        rotor2box.delete("1.0", END)
        rotor2box.insert("1.0", rotorticks[1])
        rotor1box.delete("1.0", END)
        rotor1box.insert("1.0", rotorticks[0])
        uinput = event.char
    except:
        sys.exit()
    # LETTER COUNT UPDATE DETECTION
    if lettercount != len(uinput):
        if lettercount < len(uinput) and len(uinput) > 1:
            if len(uinput) - lettercount > 1:
                for i in range(1, len(uinput) - lettercount + 1):
                    active = alpha.find(uinput[i - 1].upper()) + 1
                    rotate(1, False)
                    encrypt()
                    outputbox.insert(END, alpha[active - 1])
            else:
                active = alpha.find(uinput[len(uinput) - 2].upper()) + 1
                rotate(1, False)
                encrypt()
                outputbox.insert(END, alpha[active - 1])
        elif lettercount > len(uinput):
            if lettercount - len(uinput) < 2:
                rotate(1, True)
                uoutput = outputbox.get("1.0", END)
                strip = uoutput[:-2]
                outputbox.delete("1.0", END)
                outputbox.insert("1.0", strip)
            else:
                rotate(lettercount - len(uinput), True)
                uoutput = outputbox.get("1.0", END)
                strip = uoutput[: ((lettercount - len(uinput)) * -1) - 1]
                outputbox.delete("1.0", END)
                outputbox.insert("1.0", strip)
        # UPDATE ROTOR WIRING BOXES
        rot1.delete("1.0", END)
        rot1.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor11)))
        rot2.delete("1.0", END)
        rot2.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor21)))
        rot3.delete("1.0", END)
        rot3.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, rotor31)))
        refl.delete("1.0", END)
        refl.insert("1.0", "".join(map(str, ref1)))
    # REDEFINE LETTERCOUNT
    lettercount = len(uinput)


window.bind("<Key>", handle_key)
window.mainloop()
```

In this example I've bound it to the root window. You might want to bind it to the input window instead.

Comment: I'm not sure `time.sleep(0.05)` will help, since it just freezes the whole program.

Comment: @BryanOakley In a [similar situation](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/python-examples/blob/main/subprocess/dicom2jpg.py#L157) it was enough to break the program's lock on the CPU. At a guess, using `sleep` makes it easier for the OS to schedule another program. In that case 50 ms was not noticable. In a GUI maybe 0.01 s would be better.